# Which Cable Should I Use to Send Serial Data From my PCB to a Raspberry Pi via USB?

Tags: serial, spi, cable, connectors

My PCB has a 16-pin male connector with a 2.54mm pitch. I was going to connect this to my Raspberry Pi via its GPIO, but I have a PiSound sitting on it now, so my only other option is to connect to it via USB and send serial data that way.

I've been looking at the FTDI USB to TTL serial cables, but don't see any with 16 PIN GPIO female connectors to attach to the PCB side.

Could anyone please recommend which cables to do / what to use in this situation? It would be much appreciated, thank you.

Connector attached to the PCB:
https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/XH-Connectors_2501series-socket-1-16P-2-5mm_C168992.html

Edit: Should I be able to use something like the FTDI FT232RL or CP2102 with the above connector?